# Heatmap figures via OpenCV

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv

According to some research done, the heatmap figures cannot be done via OpenCV. There is some other color maps (HSV, jet...) but not the one I'm looking for.
Do you suggest something to display them?

Comment: What heat map figures are you referring to? It is possible to display heat maps with OpenCV. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: @bjoernz How to display heat maps? I 'm having an image and I would like to display it as a heat figure. That 's my problem

Comment: I gave minus as this question suggests that it is not possible to heatmaps using openCV. It is as it was proven in answers below. Try to avoid "suggesting" in your questions

Answer (score 5):

You can display a heat map like this:

```
cv::Mat heatmap = getHeatMap(grayscaleImage); // create your heat map from a grayscale image (CV_8UC1)
cv::imshow("Heat Map", heatmap); // display your heat map
waitkey(0); // make sure the application does not close immediately
```

`getHeatMap()` would look something like this (not tested):

```
cv::Mat getHeatMap(cv::Mat input) // input is of type CV_8UC1, return is of type CV_8UC3
{
    cv::Mat result(input.rows, input.cols, CV_8UC3);
    for (int yy = 0; yy < input.rows; ++yy)
    {
        for (int xx = 0; xx < input.cols; ++xx)
        {
            int pixelValue = input.at<uchar>(yy, xx);
            if (pixelValue < 128) {
                result.at<cv::Vec3b>(yy, xx) = cv::Vec3b(0, 0 + 2*pixelValue, 255 - 2 * pixelValue);
            } else {
                result.at<cv::Vec3b>(yy, xx) = cv::Vec3b(0 + 2*pixelValue, 255 - 2 * pixelValue, 0);
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: getHeatMap ?? I don't get it.

Comment: I tried the ColorMap of OpenCV for the hope of getting a heat map, but, is there a predefined functions which deals with that?

Comment: I don't know of any predefined function, but creating a heat map gradient is not that difficult...

Answer (score 4):

Check out `cv::applyColorMap(InputArray src, OutputArray dst, int colormap)`, it is at least available since [OpenCV 2.4](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.13/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/colormaps.html?highlight=applycolormap#void%20applyColorMap(InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20int%20colormap)).

Here is an minimal example from [this website](https://www.learnopencv.com/applycolormap-for-pseudocoloring-in-opencv-c-python/):

```
using namespace cv; 

Mat im_gray = imread("pluto.jpg", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
Mat im_color;
applyColorMap(im_gray, im_color, COLORMAP_JET);
```